# C# - TypeInitializationException when loading image files to Emgu cv for a C# console application?

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application, desktop-application, emgucv

I am working on Emgu cv as a console application and I was trying to load an jpeg format image file from computer disk.I have tried the following ways but nothing is working?

```
Image input = Image.FromFile("C://Users//...//Image.jpg");
Bitmap master = (Bitmap)input;
Image<Gray,byte> InputImage = new Image<Gray,byte>(master);
RecognizeFaces(InputImage);
```

And this way too

```
Image<Bgr,byte> inputImage = new Image<Bgr,byte>("C:\\Users\...\Image.jpeg");
Image<Gray,byte> grayFrame = inputImage.Convert<Gray,byte>();
```

Both ways Its not working.Any other option? It stops running here

```
    _ptr = CvInvoke.cvCreateImageHeader(new Size(cols, rows), CvDepth, numberOfChannels);
```

in a class known to be Image.cs of Emgu cv.And it throws type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' Exception.The File path is perfect/correct.the error looks like this.
The inner exception is "System.BadImageFormatException An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format Exception for hresult 0x8007000B." Configuration manager and build target are the same both any cpu.
http://www.mediafire.com/view/myfiles/#6557l4iwzpza7m5
 Could you please tell me what i am doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about this exception already, they almost all have the same answer.  It is a deployment problem, you are using the wrong version of the native DLLs used by Emgu.  Right-click your EXE project, Properties, Build tab.  Change the Platform target setting.  If it is AnyCPU now then change it to x86.  Or the other way around, it isn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. My solution was to change the target platform of the application to explicitly "x64". (I have a 64bit system and the 64bit libraries)

Answer (score 0):

The delimiters in the file path are reversed for Windows. Did you try it like this "C:\Users\...\Image.jpeg"? (instead of "//")

You can check it with File.Exists to be sure.

I would look for mistakes like that (simple mistakes). Generally I don't remember having problems loading an image from file with Emgu.

Comment: Its not working.Any other option? It stops running here 
            _ptr = CvInvoke.cvCreateImageHeader(new Size(cols, rows), CvDepth, numberOfChannels);

in a Image.cs class of Emgu cv.And it throws the exception that i mentioned in my question.

in the program.cs file.

Comment: @Sisay I am also encountered with same issue. Did you get solution?